# Mongoose schema "this" keyword returns undefined

Tags: mongoose

I have the following schema which has two fields:

-finalGrade is entered by user

-numericGrade is derived from finalGrade

The problem is: No matter which value from the finalGrade's enum I enter, the numericGrade will always be 164. As I tried to escape the value of this.finalGrade, I found out that it always return "undefined".

How do I get the correct value returned?

Thanks in advance!

(Referenced: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions-and-this )

EDIT 2: entirety of Schema updated

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Student = mongoose.model('Student');
const Course = mongoose.model('Course');

let enrolmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        student: {
            type: Number, 
            min: 1000000000, 
            max: 9999999999, 
            required: [true, "missing studentID"],
            validate:{
                isAsync: true,
                validator: function(v, cb){
                    Student.find({studentID: v}, function(err,docs){
                        cb(docs.length != 0);
                    })
                },
                message: 'Student does not exist...'
            }

        },
        course: {type: String, minlength: 3, maxlength: 3, required: [true, "missing courseID"]},
        semester:{
            type: Number, 
            validate:
            {
                validator: function(v){
                    return Number.isInteger(v) && v>= 1 && v<= 8;
                },
            message: "semester must be an integral value from [1 to 8]"
            }
        },
        finalGrade: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['E', 'G', 'P', 'F', '']
        },

        numericGrade:{
            type: Number,
            default: function()
            {
                console.log(escape("This is finalGrade:" +this.finalGrade)); //debugging
                if(this.finalGrade==='E'){
                    return 5;
                }
                else if(this.finalGrade==='G'){
                    return 4;
                }
                else if(this.finalGrade==='P'){
                    return 3;
                }
                else if(this.finalGrade==='F'){
                    return 2;
                }
                else if(this.finalGrade===''){
                    return 1;
                }
                else return 164;
            }
        }

})
mongoose.model('Enrolment', enrolmentSchema);
```

EDIT: Added document creation code as requested:

```
function insertEnrolmentRecord(req,res){
    var enrolment = new Enrolment();
    enrolment.student = req.body.student;
    enrolment.course = req.body.course;
    enrolment.semester= req.body.semester;
    enrolment.finalGrade= req.body.finalGrade;
    enrolment.save((err,doc)=>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/enrolment/add_failed')
        }
        else res.redirect('/enrolment');

   })
}
```

Comment: How do you try it?  Creating a document or updating a document?

Comment: I try it by creating document.

Comment: Can you add that code to the question?

Comment: I added it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you checked if req.body.finalGrade is not undefined?  Please check  console.log(req.body.finalGrade)

Comment: It is correctly extracted. console.log("req.body.finalGrade is: "+ escape(req.body.finalGrade)); returned req.body.finalGrade is: F

Comment: Ok good, can you also add the all Enrolment schema code to the question?

Comment: I updated the code as you requested. Thank you.

Comment: Found the reason, will post answer.

Comment: Please check my answer, and don't forget to  mark it as answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason default option seems not to work, when you create your enrolment document like that.

But it seems to work when you use the **constructor** form.

Try like this:

```
function insertEnrolmentRecord(req, res) {

  const { student, course, semester, finalGrade } = req.body;

  let enrolment = new Enrolment({ student, course, semester, finalGrade });

  console.log(enrolment.numericGrade); // even here it will work

  enrolment.save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/enrolment/add_failed')
    }
    else res.redirect('/enrolment');

  })
}
```